# How to replace UI elements instead of just adding to them to the existing UI.| JavaScript , Fetch API | Dom Manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, fetch, codepen

So I have a small project, I'm currently learning about APIs and how to work with them.
My project lets you search for and display characters from a TV show. The data comes from the API.
I'm able to get the data from the API no problem, and I can display them in my UI. But if I try to make a second search for a second character, the data from the first character isn;t replaces, the new data is just added under the first character (I know this may be confusing, sorry I can't explain it any better). I asked yesterday and got some rude responses, so I tried to reword my answer.

Basically my issue is : When you make multiple searches, the 'old' character's information continues to be displayed, and the most recent search data is just appended to the bottom of the page.

Below I will leave the JavaScript, as well as a link to the codepen. Any help is appreciated, this has been kicking my butt for a few days now, lol.

```
// UI Elements
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const lastLocation = document.getElementById("location");
const status = document.getElementById("status");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
const charArea = document.getElementById("charArea");
const search = document.getElementById("search");

// Get the data from the api
async function getCharacter(character) {
  const characterResponse = await fetch(
    `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${character}`
  );
  // characterInfo will now contain all our data
  const characterInfo = await characterResponse.json();
  const charArr = characterInfo.results;

  charArr.forEach(function (character) {
    displayCharacters(character);
  });

  return characterInfo;
}

// Add event listener
submit.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  charArea.innerHTML = "";
  let name = search.value;
  getCharacter(name);
  e.preventDefault();
});

let output = "";
function displayCharacters(character) {
  output += `
  <div class="card mt-3 text-center">
        <img src="${character.image}" alt="..." class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${character.name}</h5>
          <p class="card-text" id="status">${character.status}</p>
          <p class="card-text" id="location">${character.location.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;

  charArea.innerHTML = output;
}
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/bmac3032/pen/KKVJdgq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works fine. output variable used in displayCharacters was in global scope. So it retained the value from previous search.

```
    // UI Elements
const name = document.getElementById("name");
const lastLocation = document.getElementById("location");
const status = document.getElementById("status");
const submit = document.getElementById("submit");
const charArea = document.getElementById("charArea");
const search = document.getElementById("search");

// Get the data from the api
async function getCharacter(character) {
  const characterResponse = await fetch(
    `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${character}`
  );
  // characterInfo will now contain all our data
  const characterInfo = await characterResponse.json();
  displayCharacters(characterInfo.results);
  return characterInfo;
}

// Add event listener
submit.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  charArea.innerHTML = "";
  let name = search.value;
  getCharacter(name);
  e.preventDefault();
});

function displayCharacters(charArr) {
  let output = "";
  charArr.forEach(function (character) {
   output += `<div class="card mt-3 text-center">
        <img src="${character.image}" alt="..." class="card-img-top" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${character.name}</h5>
          <p class="card-text" id="status">${character.status}</p>
          <p class="card-text" id="location">${character.location.name}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  });
  charArea.innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much. I know the code was bloated and had a lot of fluff(didn't need to be included). You da man!